# Are there going to be two instances for a bean if I write @managed bean annotation and define same in faces-config.xml

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean, faces-config

In my application in some places we are using @ManagedBean annoation for Person bean and for the same Person bean we defining in the faces-confing.xml like below at the same time.

```
@ManagedBean("name=person")
 @SessionScoped
 Public class Person{


}
```

faces-config.xml

```
<managed-bean>
     <managed-bean-name>person</managed-bean-name>
     <managed-bean-class>com.test.sample.Person</managed-bean-class>
     <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

my question is does this approach create two instances for the Person bean or it does matter if I do this? Does this have any effect on performance of my application If I do this for every Bean in my application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a priority defined for this case. `@ManagedBean` annotation avoids having to configure an entry in `faces-config.xml` but, if you have both, the `<managed-bean>` entry overrides the annotation.

In your case, there'll be only one instance configured like your `faces-config.xml` entry. In your case, both approaches are configured the same way but, should you change your `faces-config.xml` entry to something like

```
<managed-bean>
     <managed-bean-name>personBean</managed-bean-name>
     <managed-bean-class>com.test.sample.Person</managed-bean-class>
     <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Your bean will be registered under `personBean` rather than `person` (which is the name defined by the annotation).