# Can't find beans annotated with @ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean, faces-config

While upgrading the JSF version of an old web application from MyFaces 1.1 to MyFaces 2.2.12, I am trying to replace the `<managed-bean>` entries in my `faces-config.xml` file with `@ManagedBean` annotations directly in the bean classes. I am using [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0) as a general guide for the migration.

For example, I am replacing something like

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>MyBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>some.package.MyBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

with

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean {
```

According to [Are there going to be two instances for a bean if I write @managed bean annotation and define same in faces-config.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750771/are-there-going-to-be-two-instances-for-a-bean-if-i-write-managed-bean-annotati), annotations are overwritten by corresponding entries in the `faces-config.xml`, so I deleted the `<managed-bean>` element in my `faces-config.xml`.

Since the project consists of several maven modules which are packed as jars individually before being deployed as a combined war file, I also tried to follow the advice from [How does JSF find beans annotated with @ManagedBean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717376/how-does-jsf-find-beans-annotated-with-managedbean) and added another `META-INF` folder containing a `faces-config.xml` to the submodule containing the bean, at the following location (respecting the accepted answer in [How to reference JSF managed beans which are provided in a JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663818/how-to-reference-jsf-managed-beans-which-are-provided-in-a-jar-file/7663898#7663898)):

```
MainProject
|  SubModule
|     |src
|       | main
|          | resources
|             | META-INF
|                | faces-config.xml
```

with the following content:

```
<faces-config
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
        version="2.2">
</faces-config>
```

Sadly, I still get the following error when trying to open the page that uses this specific bean:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'MyBean' resolved to null
```

Since I am using JSF for bean management, I followed the JSF part of the instructions in [Identifying and solving javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128395/identifying-and-solving-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-target-unreachable) but even after verifying the individual points mentioned there, I still get the same error.

I am using Tomcat 7 as servlet container, which - according to http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html - supports servlet specification up to version 3.0, which, in turn, should suffice for JSF 2.2, which - if I understand correctly - requires at least servlet spec 2.5, according to http://myfaces.apache.org/core22/.

I have already searched quite a lot for the cause of the problem (as mentioned, I tried several of the SO articles mentioned above), but still can't solve the problem. I would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: Small suggestion: With JSF 2.3, the `@ManagedBean` annotation is deprecated in favour of using the CDI `@Named`. Wouldn't now be the right time to switch to that directly instead of @ManagedBean?

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for the suggestion. I considered upgrading to CDI and the `@Named` annotation, but ran into many other problems. But perhaps you are right and I should try to solve those problems instead of getting something to work that will be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found in the `@ManagedBean` Javadoc:

> The value of the `ManagedBean.name` attribute is taken to be the `managed-bean-name`. If the value of the name attribute is unspecified or is the empty `String`, the `managed-bean-name` is derived from taking the unqualified class name portion of the fully qualified class name and converting the first character to lower case. For example, if the `ManagedBean` annotation is on a class with the fully qualified class name `com.foo.Bean`, and there is no name attribute on the annotation, the `managed-bean-name` is taken to be `bean`. The fully qualified class name of the class to which this annotation is attached is taken to be the `managed-bean-class`.

So your bean is named `myBean` and not `MyBean`. If you want it to be `MyBean`, provide the name with the annotation: `@ManagedBean(name = "MyBean")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Unfortunately, I already tried  to solve the problem  that way by setting the name with `(name = "MyBean")` (and just tried it again), but I still get the same error: `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'MyBean' resolved to null`

Comment: I am getting crazy here. I have tried putting the META-INF folder and the contained `faces-config.xml` into every imaginable location, but the error remains the same.